# Lost in testing Redux vs Sinon/React

Tags: reactjs, redux, sinon, enzyme

Im completely lost on how to test the React components itself which include XHR calls. I have below items

- LoginForm
- Redux with action + reducer
- Sinon (for spy/xhr stuff)
- Chai

Below is some basic setup code. Please note that its not the full code but i guess you get the idea:

**Form**

```react
class Form extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      username: null,
      password: null
    };
    this.handleForm = this.handleForm.bind(this);
  }

  handleForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.dispatch(authenticateUser(this.state.username, this.state.password));
  }

  render() {
    <Form>
  }
}
```

**Action**

```react
export function authenticateUser(username, password) {

  return function(dispatch, getState) {
    dispatch({type: 'AUTHENTICATION_USER'});

    fetch(getState().config.login_endpoint, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: {
        username: username,
        password: password
      }
    }).then(function (data) {
      if(data.status === 404) {
        dispatch({type: 'AUTHENTICATION_USER_NOTFOUND', payload: data.statusText});
      } else {
        dispatch({type: 'AUTHENTICATION_USER_FULFILLED', payload: data.json()});
      }
    }).catch(function (error) {
      dispatch({type: 'AUTHENTICATION_USER_REJECTED', payload: error.message});
    });
  };
}
```

**Reducer**

```react
export default function (state = {
  loading: false,
  errorMessage: null,
  passwordSent: false
}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'AUTHENTICATION_USER':
    return {...state, loading: true, errorMessage:null};

  case 'AUTHENTICATION_USER_NOTFOUND':
  case 'AUTHENTICATION_USER_REJECTED':
    return {...state, loading: false, errorMessage: action.payload};

  case 'AUTHENTICATION_USER_FULFILLED':
    window.location = '/';
    break;
  }
  return state;
}
```

To test all this i setup a few test cases:

```react
describe('components/LoginForm', () => {
  it('should push username and password in xhr call after form submit');
  it('redirects in case of succesfull login to the configured endpoint');
  it('should show an user error on a 404 response');
  it('should show an user error on a 500 response');
});
```

Testing of all the internal component stuff is already finished but no idea how we can handle the XHR stuff and also the redux events. I checked this page as reference but i really dont get the idea and it is also focussed on `Jest` instead
http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html

Hope that someone could bump me into the correct direction on how to handle this.

Thanks

Comment: `window.location = '/';` this should not be inside reducer. This is IO operation. Reducers should not perform side effects.

Comment: I totally understand but please do not bother. This is for legacy where im not using a SPA app overall but just only for the login form at this point. The rest will come later and then we redirect as should ofcourse

Comment: you are not unit testing. try to isolate your tests to a single unit. your component tests should be about which functions it calls directly as a result of something happening. on the other hand, testing your redux state has nothing to do with react.